# Numpy creation fromfunction

Tags: numpy

I need something like this

```
def qqq(i,j):
    if i+j>2:
        return 0.5
    else:
        return 0
n=3
dcdt=np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: qqq(i,j)*i*j, (n,n), dtype=int)
```

but with more complicated qqq. But it leads to the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I know the problem is that function is called once. How can I do such array creation with the "if-elif-else" structure in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn your `qqq` function into something like:

```
def qqq(i, j):
    return np.where(i + j > 2, 0.5, 0)
```

See [`np.where`'s docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for details.